# Realm sync permissions for flexibly-named partitions based on user id

Tags: c#, .net-core, realm

I'm new to Realm Sync (and Realm). I'm trying to convert a REST / SQL Server system to Realm Sync (to avoid having to write my own local-device caching code).

I got a simple configuration working, with a single API-key user and the null partition, read and write permissions just set to `true`.

But for my more complex application, I want smaller sub-partitions to reduce the amount of data that needs to be cached on local devices, and I want the sub-partitions to be able to be created dynamically by the client. Ideally, I would like to allow an API-key user to connect to any partition whose name starts with their user id (or some other known string, e.g. the profile name). But I can't find a way to get a "starts with" condition into the permissions.

My best attempt was to try setting Read and Write sync permissions to:

```
{
  "%%partition": {
    "$regex": "^%%user.id"
  }
}
```

but my client just fails to connect, saying `Permission denied (BIND, REFRESH)`. (Yes, I tried using `"$regex": /^%%user.id/` but the Realm UI rejected that syntax.) The Realm Sync log says "user does not have permission to sync on partition (ProtocolErrorCode=206)".
[image: user does not have permission to sync on partition (ProtocolErrorCode=206)]
As you can see in the log image, the partition name was equal to the user id for this test.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, how do I set up the Sync Permissions to make it work?

Comment: Or should I just leave the sync permissions as "true" and rely on my own app logic? Is that safe? Is it possible to get a list of all the available partitions? (If the latter, then I would consider this not a secure solution.)

Comment: If you haven't read this [Partition Strategy](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/partition-strategies/#std-label-partition-strategies) you should as it's critical to understanding dynamic partitioning, which is what you are doing. Then read the [Sync Rules](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/rules/) and then to answer your question [Sync Permissions](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/permissions/#std-label-sync-permissions) as there are example there just like what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks. I have read all of those pages, but they're not that helpful. All of the examples have hard-coded partition names; I want to be able to create new partitions on the fly. All, that is, except the last example on that last page, which uses a function - but doesn't actually explain where or how to install such a function. Unless - can I somehow add the user custom_data to one of my realm partitions? Then I could just add new partition names as needed.. but it wouldn't be very scalable once the list gets long.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue; partitions are often created 'on-the-fly'. For example; if a new user signs up, they will be assigned a uid which would then be used as a partition key for that users data. That's totally on the fly. Or for example, a chat app where each chat has its own partition key. Again, that's very dynamic (on-the-fly). Look at the example in the *function rules* section; `"name": "canReadPartition",  "arguments": ["%%partition"]` which says *function looks up the user's permissions for the partition from a collection*. That means `%%partition` could be any value.

Comment: I guess I was just hoping there might be a simpler way. Ok, I'll try writing a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a function. If, like me, you're new to Realm Sync and not fluent in Javascript, don't worry - it turns out to be not too hard to do, after all. (Thanks [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061496/realm-sync-permissions-for-flexibly-named-partitions-based-on-user-id#comment122113288_69061496) for encouraging me to try it!)

I followed the instructions on the [Define a Function](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/define-a-function/) page to create my `userCanAccessPartition` function like this:

```
exports = function(partition){
  return partition.startsWith(context.user.id);
};
```

Then I set my sync permissions to:

```
{
  "%%true": {
    "%function": {
      "name": "userCanAccessPartition",
      "arguments": ["%%partition"]
    }
  }
}
```